# Powershell script to activate HDR in Windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, hdr, streamdeck

I've scoured the net for resources on this, to no avail. I cannot find the syntax to toggle HDR in Windows 10.

As it currently stands, the GUI function for this is buried in a menu, and is a huge pain in the ass to turn on and off per application as needed.

Ideally I'd like to see if there's an ability to specify per monitor, but given how wonky this implementation seems to be on Microsoft's part, just being able to activate it on my primary display would be enough.

Thank in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the registry.

Turn on:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001' -Name 'FeatureTestControl' -PropertyType DWORD -Value '9240' -Force
```

Turn off:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Class\{4d36e968-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0001' -Name 'FeatureTestControl' -PropertyType DWORD -Value '9250' -Force
```

After the change you have to restart the system to apply.

Registry entry and values from here: [windowscentral: How to disable adaptive contrast on the Surface Pro and Surface Book](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-adapative-contrast-surface)

Please also note:

> Some users have noted that any time there is a significant Windows
>   update this setting is reset to default (9240), so you may need to
>   redo this edit once or twice a year.

Comment: Sorry for the late replay - just now saw this. 

While that is good to know, I'm not sure rebooting my system is any faster than going to a menu to check a drop down box. I was looking for something that would be a relatively easy, on-the-fly scriptable behavior, but if HDR toggling simply isn't supported in that way, then so be it.