# Setting Windows 10 HDR on/off or HDR/SDR balance from command line?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, display, hdr

Is there a way to enable/disable HDR on Windows 10? This would be useful for turning it on before launching HDR content and off afterward.

With HDR setting on, SDR content is dim unless the HDR/SDR balance it adjusted. This can be done in the display preferences, but despite it showing the desired setting, when changing between users it always defaults to 0 until the slider is nudged.

Is there a way to adjust this from the command line? It can then be added as a scheduled task (on logon for example).

Related: [Powershell script to activate HDR in Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61487861/powershell-script-to-activate-hdr-in-windows-10)

This requires a reboot, but doing so in display setting does not, so ideally there's a way to do it immediately from the command line.

Comment: ever found out how to change the balance from command line?